# science fiction dystopian future society

Tags: story-identification, fritz-leiber, harry-harrison

I recall a story from the seventies with a character named The Grand Guignol "Guig" and a host of other borrowed identities, where a group of people skirt around sites of urban decay.  One of the group is a woman who gets around totally nude and would "verbally cut to pieces anyone who even appeared to notice". It seemed like something by Harry Harrison or Fritz Leiber, and the closest I've found so far was Alfred Bester, but it's very hard to get in order to find out.

Comment: You've described some characters. Does the story also have a plot or a story line, or is it just characterization?

Answer (score 9):

There's a decent chance that it's Alfred Bester's *[Extro](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2987564-extro)*

[image: Book Cover - Extro]

From [this review](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/548843/):

> The story is set on a future Earth, at a time when humanity has spread to some of the other planets and moons, but no further. The hero, nicknamed Guig (don't ask) is a Moleman – short for Molecular Man, potentially immortal although capable of being killed by catastrophic physical damage. Such men (and women) were created by chance, through experiencing a deep shock at the molecular level from being faced by the certainty of imminent death before being saved at the last instant by a freak accident. These circumstances were so rare that that the secret Group of Molemen was very small, varying in age from a mere century or so to thousands of years.
>
> Guig lives with a precocious young teenage girl who has adopted him and has some unusual abilities that make her useful as his assistant. Another key character is a Cherokee scientist who becomes the latest recruit to the Group, but in the process becomes linked to Extro, the all-pervading computer system which runs just about everything. The problem is that Extro appears to be going off the rails and is starting to wage war against humanity. Even worse, the Molemen gradually realise that one of their number has gone rogue, and is working with Extro to kill them all.

Found with a search for *science fiction "guig"*

It was apparently also released as *The Computer Connection*, [this review](http://blog.worldswithoutend.com/2012/09/gmrc-review-the-computer-connection-by-alfred-bester/) mentioning where the protagonist's name comes from:

> There is a Group of eccentric immortals, who have all come into being after a shocking near-death experience.  Some of them are actual historical celebrities, but others simply take on names that best describe their interests. Guig’s name comes from the “Grand Guignol”, and he earned it through his obsession with recruiting new immortals.  Unfortunately, it’s difficult to orchestrate an experience of horrific near-death followed by a miraculous save, so all his attempts have ended in failure.  Mostly, he just kills people in terrible ways—but with the best of intentions.

Comment: If this is the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: And if so, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153320/story-id-immortals-prone-to-cancer/153331#153331

Comment: "Mostly, he just kills people in terrible ways—but with the best of intentions."  That's an awesome tag line! :)

Comment: Yes, it's Extro aka The Computer Connection. One of my favourite books!

Comment: In a magazine (Galaxy?) it was called *The Indian Giver* if memory serves.

Comment: Other notable quotes: *We call Christ Jacy because if you use his real name it sounds like you're swearing* and *We think Hic may be from the late Pleistocene or early Holocene and got his charge in some cataclysm that was dramatic enough to make a Neanderthal aware. Who knows? Maybe he got clobbered by a meteor or trampled by a Hairy Mastodon.*

Comment: This may be where Douglas Adams got the inspiration for [Bowerick Wowbagger the Infinitely Prolonged](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Bowerick_Wowbagger) from _Life, the Universe, and Everything_...

Comment: That cover illo is up there on the "least relevant to book" scale, at least from what i remember of the book.

Comment: @grandguignol: You can still accept this one by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, then post your other story query as a new question.